# Error message "App.exe" stopped working

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer, inno-setup

I have made an app, and want to distribute it to other people for testing purpose. I have made the setup using `InnoSetup`. The setup is working perfectly fine and creates the required directories and shortcuts perfectly. But the problem is that as soon as I click on the "myApp.exe" file, instead of opening the file a error message pops up saying that 
`myApp.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem`
I have made sure that the correct .Net framework is installed on the user's computer. I have been trying to get rid of this error from the past 4 days, but couldn't get rid of it. I made the application on windows 7 and tried running it on windows 8, when this error message comes. Earlier I made the setup using the 'Install Shield' project in visual studio 2012 and that setup was working correctly in both windows 7 and 8. Unfortunately, I couldn't get a computer running windows 7 other than my computer, to check whether the `InnoSetup` setup is working on windows 7 or not. 
There is nothing in the "App's" code that will prevent it from running on windows 8.
I had read somewhere that when you run the "App" as administrator the "exact" error message pops up. But that is also not happening.  What could be the possible reasons for it?
How can I get the exact error message, so as to know  why this is happening?

Comment: Are you maybe using third party libraries, that are not included with your binary?

Comment: No, that's not the case. I am not using any third-party libraries

Comment: Check the event log: on the start screen, type "Event Viewer", tap or click to launch it and in the tree on the left, click "Windows Logs">"Application". There you should find the actual error.

Comment: You can also use the [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx)-event to display a custom error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your `Main` method (it's usually in Program.cs) and add the following to it:

```
try
{
    // put all the existing code here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Unexpected exception");
}
```

This should show you the error if it's a runtime exception rather than a missing DLL.

The most likely kind of problem other than a missing DLL is that you are trying to load a file from your application directory using a relative path.  By default apps run by Inno do not have a working directory specified, so this will fail.  You can fix this either by specifying a working directory or (preferred) by changing your application to use full paths by internally combining them with the application's path (via `Application.ExecutablePath` or similar).

Comment: thanks for the exception part, I'll look into that, but can you tell why isn't any exception raised when I install it using `InnoSetup` in my PC

Comment: That suggests that it is actually a missing library (which you do have on your PC).  Check the dependencies of your application.